# Is this a bug: There are no review queues available to you?

Tags: support

I was looking through the website, when I came to my profile. Then, spontaneously, I decided to go check the review queues out. When I clicked on the review queues icon this is how it looked:

[image: Bug]

Is this a bug? I have 1,013 reputation, but I am not able to access the review queues. Please note that I was able to access review queues before...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eureka! The problem is that I used all my votes today, and since it the system wants me to be able upvote posts that are good, and downvote the posts that need a lot of improvement, it won't let me access the review queues because I wouldn't be able to vote!

Answer (score 6):

As you [mentioned](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3212/is-this-a-bug-there-are-no-review-queues-available-to-you/3213#3213), the reason this time is that you used up all your daily votes. Voting is essential to both First Posts and Late Answers; without it, there's not much of a point to reviewing.

For the benefit of future viewers of the question, let me document all possible cases for seeing "there are no review queues available to you"). Feel free to edit if I missed anything.

- You have between 500 and 2000 reputation and used up all your daily votes (meaning you can't review in FP or LA, the only queues you have access to).
- You're on a [review ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/review-suspension/info).
- You've used up your daily 20 reviews (or 40 if the queue is overflowing) for every queue you have access to.
- When you have between 500 and 2000 reputation, you don't have access to any review queues on meta, so you'll always see the message on meta.